# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gconcord’

Tags: r, slurm, r-package

I'm trying to use R package "gconcord".
I'm running my codes in a centos server equipped with a workload manager Slurm.
To simplify my situation, I introduce a pair of simple codes.

test.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --partition=cpu
#SBATCH --job-name='test'
#SBATCH --output=test-%A.out

/opt/ohpc/pub/apps/R/3.6.3/bin/Rscript test.R
```

test.R :

```
require(gconcord)
```

When I use `sbatch test.sh` on command line, no error occurs.
However, when I use `system("sbatch test.sh")` in R, I got the following error.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gconcord’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/seonghuncho/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/gconcord/libs/gconcord.so':
  libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Since I have to run a lot of shell scripts for my simulation study, system function in R should be used. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem for another package and tried this:

go to your home directory

```
nano .bash_profile
```

and include the following lines before export path:

```
export PATH=/home/seonghuncho/.local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/seonghuncho/.local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

source .bash_profile
```

Comment: I am glad!! I am also using cluster like you and having some other problems while compiling stan model.. Can you check this error [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912113/fatal-error-features-h-no-such-file-or-directory-during-model-compilation-cento] whether or not you are familiar? @SeonghunCho